# QueryDSL: Syntax error parsing during rounding

Tags: java, sql, db2, querydsl

```
@Embeddable
public class Birthday {

    private LocalDate value;

    // Constructors, getters and setters
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Birthday birthday;

     // Constructors, getters and setters
}
```

Query with deviding by 3:

```
List<Person> sortedPersons = query.selectFrom(person)
                               .orderBy(person.birthday.value.month().divide(3).ceil().asc())
                                .fetch();
```

Query using template:

```
 List<Person> sortedPersons = query.selectFrom(person)
                                   .orderBy(Expressions.dateTemplate(Integer.class, "QUARTER({0})", person.birthday.value).asc())
                                    .fetch();
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException:
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select 
from Person person
order by ceil(extract(month from person.birthday.value) / 3) asc].
[3165, 3254] The order by item is not a valid expression.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:157) ~[com.ibm.websphere.appserver.thirdparty.eclipselink.2.7_1.0.76.jar:?]
    at [internal classes]
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:101) ~[querydsl-jpa-4.2.2.HL-20230109.202119-8.jar:?]
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:94) ~[querydsl-jpa-4.2.2.HL-20230109.202119-8.jar:?]
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.fetch(AbstractJPAQuery.java:201) ~[querydsl-jpa-4.2.2.HL-20230109.202119-8.jar:?]
```

Birthday field is stored in the database as DATE

The problem is that if I remove method `.ceil()` then everything works great, but rounding is important for me without round up my query return incorrect data (I need to sort by quarter). I tried to use templates for this one but I did not help.

If I do not use `.ceil` I have this data with such ordering.

1. 01/11/2023
2. 03/30/2023
3. 04/29/2023
4. 03/31/2023
5. 03/30/2023
6. 08/18/2023

Comment: *but rounding is important for me* Please explain

Comment: explained this in detail

Comment: "Incorrect" in what way?

Comment: explained this in detail

Comment: Exactly, February and March are the same quarter. The four quarters are: January to March, April to June, July to September, and October to December

Comment: Sorry that comment was not quite what I meant. It's an ordering strategy and I don't see how rounding is relevant

Comment: Rounding is necessary because without it, the 4th and 5th months fall into the first quarter, and only the 12th month falls into the fourth quarter

Comment: *4th and 5th months fall into the first quarter* Correct. Quartile index 1. *12th month* quartile index 3

Comment: Then 3th and 4th months have index 1 but 3th month should be 1 quarter and 4th should be 2nd quarter.

Comment: No, 3rd month March is in quartile 0

Comment: I agree with you, your logic has sense but I have this data) Updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed sql-template. As it turned out, you need to take out a variable in the template itself :)

```
  List<Person> sortedPersons = query.selectFrom(person)
                                   .orderBy(Expressions.dateTemplate(Integer.class, "SQL('QUARTER(?)', {0})", person.birthday.value).asc())
                                    .fetch();
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem now I did a demo in pure Java using *your* dates. It's because `java.time.Month` is *not* zero-indexed. Run the following and note the correction (subtraction, not rounding) makes the results as they should be:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

public class BirthdayQuartiles {
    record Birthday(String name, String date) {
        static DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu");
        final static String bformat = "%s : %s (%s)";
        LocalDate getAsLocalDate() {
            return LocalDate.parse(date, dtf);
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return bformat.formatted(name, date, getAsLocalDate().getMonth());
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Birthday[] birthdays = {
            new Birthday("Charles", "01/11/2023"),
            new Birthday("Diana", "03/30/2023"),
            new Birthday("Margaret", "04/29/2023"),
            new Birthday("Edward", "03/31/2023"),
            new Birthday("Beatrice", "03/30/2023"),
            new Birthday("William", "08/18/2023")
        };
        Map<Integer, List<Birthday>> quartiles = Arrays.stream(birthdays)
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Birthday::getAsLocalDate))
            // Adjust key as java.time.Month is NOT zero-indexed
            .collect(groupingBy(b ->(b.getAsLocalDate().getMonth().getValue()-1)/3, toList()));

        final String quartileFormat = "Birthday(s) in quartile %d: %s%n";
        quartiles.entrySet().stream()
            .forEach(e ->System.out.println(quartileFormat.formatted(e.getKey(), e.getValue())));  
    }
}
```